# "Я этого не люблю"

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

"Я этого не люблю" и "я это не люблю". Есть ли тут разница?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Глаголы с частицей "НЕ" обычно управляют существительным или местоимением в родительном падеже, а не в винительном. Это относится к существительным, имеющим отвлеченное, абстрактное значение. Например: Я не испытываю чувства любви к кому-то. У меня не возникло сомнений в чем-то. Я не имею правА что-то делать. Если же существительное обозначает конкретное понятие, то употребляется винительный падеж: Я не вижу стол.

Answer (score 0):

как зовут
сколько лет
где живёшь
где учиться

Comment: Да не при делах я, гражданин следователь!

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае разницы в употреблении я не вижу.
Указательное местоимение это/этого здесь всегда означает действие или отвлеченное существительное, действие по глаголу. В крайнем случае - какой-то набор, не несущий конретных слов: "Меня угощали тем-то и тем-то, а я это/этого не люблю". В остальных случаях использовались бы обычные личные местоимения: его, её и т.д.

Может быть, правда, тут присутсвует некая стилистическая тенденция: "это не люблю" - акцент на "это", "этого не люблю" - на "не люблю", но всё это очень субъективно.

Comment: Не очень поняла, что показывает пример с угощением? Мне кажется "я это не люблю" - не люблю ТО, чем угощают, а "я этого не люблю" - не люблю, КОГДА меня угощают.

Comment: Он показывает разуцу в употреблении, как я её вижу.

Comment: Не очень... Ну и бог с ним! Некогда сейчас... Я буду говорить, что все люблю - вот и нет проблемы ))))

Comment: Ну это не решение проблемы в целом. 
Странно, мне казалось, что мысль я свою изложил вполне доходчиво. Можно, разумеется, не соглашаться, но что можно не понять...  
Ладно, подобные вопросы возникают постоянно, до слудеющего раза.